# AJAX/Pusher is not working properly in Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm implementing a real time chat with Pusher and Ruby on Rails.

I am using this form to send AJAX requests to my MessageController and in the MessageController#create, it responds this call with running create.js and Pusher triggers some-channel.

```
// show.html.erb

<%= form_for Message.new, :remote => true do |f| %>
                           <%= f.text_field :content, id: 'new_message' %>
                           <%= f.hidden_field :conversation_id, :value => @conversation.id %>
                           <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                           <%= f.submit "Send" %>
                         <% end %>

// MessageController.rb

    def create
            @message = Message.create(content: params[:message][:content], user_id: params[:message][:user_id])
            conversation = Conversation.find(params[:message][:conversation_id])
        conversation.messages << @message
            Pusher['some-channel'].trigger('my_event', {
          message: @message
        })
        end


// create.js.erb

var pusher = new Pusher('PUSHER KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('some-channel');
  channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
    $(".chats").append("<%= escape_javascript render(@message) %>");

});
$("#new_message")[0].reset();
```

However, when I first submit  the form, nothing is appended to the page. In second submit, alert pops up twice showing the message I've just sent; first and second message I've just sent is appended to the page. In third submit, alert pops up three times showing the message I've just sent; first,second and third message is appended to the page and so on. I can't seem to find the problem. I understand that message is sent properly but somehow everytime it appends incorrect messages.

Comment: Burak, I'm facing the same problem at the moment. Have you been able to solve your problem? Is the create.js.erb version working well? I mean I'd like to use the reusable _message partial as well, but only saw json versions on the web.

Comment: I did solved it, but actually not really sure how :p However it is about the subscription to the channel. If you dynamically subscribe to the channel with after ajax loads, it connects to the channel multiple times or creating the pusher object multiple times, I am not sure which one is true. And create.js.erb version is working pretty well, however I am not happy with it and will change it later, move to a more JSON based approach. Anyway, if you need further detail, contact me at burakozmen@outlook.com.

Comment: Burak, I'm going to send a mail asap! THX

Comment: Hey Burak, can you help me with this one then?